# iOS DynamoDB: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel supported data types

Tags: ios, amazon-dynamodb

Does anyone know what type of fields I can have in my iOS DynamoDB `AWSDynamoDBObjectModel` subclass? Specifically, does it support `NSData`?